# How to add a new ROS core package without new build of all core package?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make-isolated, roscore, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to build the ROS from the source on Rasbian Buster (R-Pi 4). I followed the instructions from this [site](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/08/01/installing-ros-melodic-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-rplidar-a1m8/).

First I installed the desktop core version with these steps:

```
rosinstall_generator desktop --rosdistro melodic --deps --tar > melodic-desktop.rosinstall
wstool init -j8 src melodic-desktop-wet.rosinstall
wstool update -j 4 -t src
```

It works. However, now I need several other packages, such as `tf2_eigen`. I check the instruction from https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source. Then, I execute

```
rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro melodic --deps --tar > melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall
```

to see the entries of the `tf2_eigen`. I inserted the `tf2_eigen` entry to the file `melodic-desktop.rosinstall`, that I created for the first time.

Then, I did

```
wstool merge -t src  melodic-desktop.rosinstall
```

to merge the new entry, and `wstool update -j 4 -t src`.

However, after I run this command

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/melodic -j2
```

to build the `tf2_eigen`, the command `catkin_make_isolated` build everything again in the src folder. I costs me two hours to build all the core packages again. How can I build the `tf2_eigen` only, without building everything again?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364315/how-to-add-a-new-ros-core-package-without-new-build-of-all-core-package?/) by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2020-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a couple of ideas:

1. Download the ros packages with apt-get, so that you don't have to compile them from source
2. catkin_make_isolated has several arguments to specify which packages should get build (for example --pkg)
3. Create an overlay workspace with only your package, this way you only have to build your underlay workspace once: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

---

Originally posted by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) with karma: 128 on 2020-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-28**:
The first idea is not possible, since there is currently no ros-melodic package for raspbian buster.
What is overlay workspace? What should I do? If the overlay workspace refers to a new paralel workspace folder, it is not my option. I don't want to have several ros-core workspaces, since I have already several project workspace.
The second idea is the suitable solution for me. Thanks @Rayman!

**Comment by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) on 2020-10-28**:
I've added a link to the overlay workspace tutorial. An overlay workspace *adds* packages on top of another workspace. This way you can chain two (or more) workspace and prevent recompiling everything. I hope it helps you.